# ExoPlayer - changing thumb in DefaultTimeBar

Tags: android, android-layout, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

As I understand from releas note of version 2.4.0 Exoplayer`SeekBar` was replaced by `DefaultTimeBar`.
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/dev-v2/RELEASENOTES.md

As I can seen, as on 19Feb2017: https://github.com/bigexxx/ExoPlayer/blob/c5db6f39a6e07b4f98364ff40476e4e213172488/library/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlaybackControlView.java
exo_progress was SeekBar type:

(line 285):
`progressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.exo_progress);`

And right now:
github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/ui/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlaybackControlView.java

it is:

(line: 384):`timeBar = (TimeBar) findViewById(R.id.exo_progress);`

DefaultTimeBar does not have method like `.setThumb()` and it seems to me that thumb is created as `Canvas` in `drawPlayhead(Canvas canvas)`.

Question: is is possible to set own thumb icon in `DefaultTimeBar`?

Comment: created also question on ExoPlayer github page:
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3337

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This option was added by ExoPlayer team after [ticket](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3337) was raised.

```
app:scrubber_drawable="@drawable/ic_scrubber"
```

Comment: Nice work, after lot of searching, found this. Saved my time, thanks.

Answer (score 13):

I didn't found an option to set a thumb icon in DefaultTimeBar.

You can copy DefaultTimeBar and customize the thumb by changing  *drawPlayhead(Canvas canvas)* method.

Also you can change it color by adding **exo_playback_control_view.xml**. (scrubber == thumb)

```
        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
            android:id="@id/exo_progress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:scrubber_color="@color/scrubberColor"
            app:played_color="@color/playedColor"
            app:unplayed_color="@color/unplayedColor"
            app:buffered_color="@color/bufferedColor"
            android:layout_height="26dp"/>
```

More information about customizing ExoPlayer’s UI components: https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/customizing-exoplayers-ui-components-728cf55ee07a

'

========== UPDATE ================

Following properties could be used in order to change the scrubber drawable:

```
    app:scrubber_drawable="@drawable/ic_scrubber"
    app:scrubber_enabled_size="24dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I need to change color of scrubber (thumb) when it is focused.
So I created a drawable like this
bg_progressbar_play_video

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/bg_progressbar_play_video_focused"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_progressbar_play_video_normal"/>
</selector>
```

And here are bg_progressbar_play_video_normal

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <size
        android:width="14dp"
        android:height="14dp" />/
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

</shape>
```

and bg_progressbar_play_video_focused

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"
    >
<size android:height="14dp" android:width="14dp"/>/
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
</shape>
```

and here is way I added the drawable to scrubber.

```
   <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/videoPlayerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:played_color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:scrubber_drawable="@drawable/bg_progressbar_play_video"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

If you just need to change the color and enabled size of scrubber (thumb), you can use these below attributes:

```
 app:scrubber_enabled_size="24dp"
 app:scrubber_color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
```

More informations about these attributes that you can customize, please read in here: https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/DefaultTimeBar.html