# ExoPlayer - Is possible programmatically change the color of the DefaultTimeBar?

Tags: customization, exoplayer

I override exo_playback_control_view.xml of exoplayer to customize it as shown in the following code. (exoplayer version 2.6.1)

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
            android:id="@id/exo_progress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            app:buffered_color="#534b20"
            app:played_color="#ffca28"
            app:unplayed_color="#515151"
            app:scrubber_drawable="@drawable/vod_seek_circle_thumb"
            app:bar_height="@dimen/vod_playback_seekbar_line_size"/>
```

I only want to use the same color for buffered_color and unplayed_color in certain situations. ex) Play the downloaded video

Is there a way to programmatically change the color of unplayed_color?

Comment: Check the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/51244861/8389762

Answer (score 0):

Get the timebar reference using:

```
 timeBar = simpleExoplayerView.findViewById(R.id.exo_progress)
```

Then, you can use this:

```
    timeBar?.setBackgroundColor(requireContext().getColor(R.color.white))
    timeBar?.setScrubberColor(requireContext().getColor(R.color.white))
    timeBar?.setPlayedColor(requireContext().getColor(R.color.white))
    timeBar?.setUnplayedColor(requireContext().getColor(R.color.transparent))
    timeBar?.setBufferedColor(requireContext().getColor(R.color.transparent))
```